# Make Twilio Forward A Dial Tone

Tags: twilio, freepbx, twilio-studio

I have a studio workflow on Twilio that handles several operations. It begins by asking for someone to press an extension. When the extension is pressed there are a few things that is done on Twilio.

The rest of my extensions are handled through FreePBX. I want that dial tone or extension to be forwarded to FreePBX but I cannot figure out how to do it.

Answer (score 0):

You will use the Connect Call To Widget with a SIP Dial, as shown below. Twilio will then send a SIP INVITE to your FreePBX (which will result in a VoIP connection).

FreePBX will then need to properly route the SIP invite to the appropriate extension.

The assumption is you are not placing the call over the public switched telephone network to a phone number directly associated with the FreePBX extension, if that is the case, you will use the same Studio widget but choose Connect Call to Single Number (the phone number that routes directly to the users extension).

[Forward Calls with Twilio Studio](https://www.twilio.com/docs/studio/tutorials/how-to-forward-calls)

[Setting Up Call Forwarding](https://support.twilio.com/hc/en-us/articles/223179908-Setting-Up-Call-Forwarding)

[image]